# .NET - does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a few apps built in ASP.NET 3.5, VS 2008.
After having to re-install VS 2008, when I go to amend any page in any system, all the controls dont seems to be recognised and Im faced with 
"[control name] does not exist in the current context"
This is for all my apps.
Also getting "failed to create app domain" in all apps as well.
Any idea's what Ive done?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Third-party controls or builtin ones?

Comment: Hi Just standard built-in ones

Comment: refreshed the references which sorted most problems, still cant create AppDomain though

Comment: This happened to me when merging a project file. It was missing the xml node to specify that the aspx.designer file is dependent upon the aspx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorted it in the command prompt with caspol -reset

Comment: When you have solved a problem yourself, you should mark your own answer as the accepted one, otherwise the question will still appear to be unresolved.

Comment: cant answer my own question for 2 days it says